# Is this a safe way to clean black mold in the attic?

Tags: attic, mold, chlorine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove/clean black mold?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/how-to-remove-clean-black-mold)

My dad says there's mold in the attic (that looks black), and he plans to spray it with a mixture of water and chlorine.

Is this a safe way to clean it?

Comment: See the answer to this question [how to remove/clean black mold](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/how-to-remove-clean-black-mold/8937#8937).  Make sure you have the mold tested before messing with it, if it is black mold; and not just mold that happens to be black, you might need professional help.