# How should I clean mold from studs?

Tags: mold

I found a water leak behind my refrigerator.  It was about 3 feet wide a 1 foot high.  I pulled the drywall and I'm running a blower and dehumidifier in the kitchen.

The studs have some mold on them.  Is there a commercial product that I should use to clean the studs?  Should I just spray it on, or should I wipe or scrub it?  I've seen others paint the studs when treating.  Is this a special paint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/how-to-remove-clean-black-mold

Answer (score 1):

Bleach and water in a spray bottle (anywhere from 10 to 25 percent bleach to water ratio) will kill mold.   Watch the over-spray and wear old clothes.